Movie about airplane, rainforest, tribe, gold and bombs
I'm trying to find the movie title.
Two pilots are tricked into carrying out an illegal military mission as a way to break out of their arrest. They are up to bombing a rainforest tribe to make the land clear for gold mining. One of the pilots refuses to kill the people with bomb and the other one tries to force him, putting a knife to his throat, because this is their only chance to break out of their situation...
Please help me to find out the title of this movie with terrific soundtrack and story I heard on radio.

At Play in the Fields of the Lord (1991) with Tom Berenger, John Lithgow and Daryl Hannah. From Wiki:

A pair of Americans, Lewis Moon and Wolf, become stranded in Mãe de Deus (Portuguese: Mother of God), an outpost in the deep Brazilian Amazon River basin, after their plane runs out of fuel.
The local police commander wants the Niaruna tribe, living upriver, to move their village so they won't be killed by gold miners moving into the area and cause trouble for him with the provincial government. The commander cuts a deal with Moon: if he and his fellow mercenary would bomb the Niaruna village from the air and drive them away, they will be given enough gasoline for their airplane to be allowed to leave.

Moon refuses to bomb the tribe, at which point Wolf holds a knife to his throat. James Cameron stated that this movie (among others) was an inspiration for the plot of Avatar. The soundtrack was composed by Krzysztof Kieślowski's go-to composer Zbigniew Preisner. Here's the trailer:



